# Remove app from BlueStacks using HD-Run.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, automation, android, bluestacks

Basically what I'm trying to understand is a way to uninstall apps from BlueStacks using CLI.
For example, you can run app like this:

```
HD-RunApp.exe Android com.nubee.valkyriecrusade com.nubee.valkyriecrusade.GameActivity
```

This will execute main game window.

```
HD-RunApp.exe Android com.estrongs.android.popcom.estrongs.android.pop.view.FileExplorerActivity
```

With this you can run ES Explorer.

Or you can restart BS from CLI like this:

```
HD-Restart.exe android
```

Is there any directions on how can I perform uninstall operation to some app?

I have tried to use ADB, but apparently at the moment its can't delete app caches/data.